# How to append some special character to a string in random position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I tried with this

```
function makeid()
{
    var chars = "!~/-^";
    var st = "It turns out tho, that if you append a string to the end of the URL that the CDN has never seen before, it will return the most recent version of the file. Bogus to be sure.";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomstring;
}
var output = makeid();
console.log(output);
```

The random string is generated with the code above now how will I append the randomly generated string to the random position of the given string.

Thanks

Comment: appending means it goes on the end, are you wanting to splice it in the middle?

Comment: @dandavis I wanna add the generated random string in different position of the given string.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
function makeid()
{
    var chars = "!~/-^";
    var st = "It turns out tho, that if you append a string to the end of the URL that the CDN has never seen before, it will return the most recent version of the file. Bogus to be sure.";
    var string_length = 8; // did not use this.
    var randomstring = '';
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*st.length + 1);
    randomstring = st.substr(0, randomNumber) + chars + st.substr(randomNumber);
    return randomstring;
}
var output = makeid();
console.log(output);
```

Here is a different way:

```
function makeid2()
{
    var chars = "!~/-^";
    var st = "It turns out tho, that if you append a string to the end of the URL that the CDN has never seen before, it will return the most recent version of the file. Bogus to be sure.";
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*st.length + 1);
    var a = st.split("");
        a.splice(randomNumber,0,chars);
        return a.join("");

}
var output2 = makeid2();
console.log(output2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array to random sort the elements.

```js
$(function(){


var st = "It turns out tho, that if you append a string to the end of the URL that the CDN has never seen before, it will return the most recent version of the file. Bogus to be sure.";


var array = st.split(" "),
    $ele = $("#result");


for( var i=0; i<8; i++){
                   
   array = array.sort(function(){  return Math.random() -0.5 });
  
   $ele.val(  $ele.val() + "\n" + i + ": " + array.join(" ")  );
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='result' style="width:100%" rows="20"></textarea>
```